# Probability of selecting 1 of n-i elements in a set of size n when choosing k elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a set of $n$ elements, I will choose uniformly at random $k$ distinct elements.

First: Given a set $S$ of $i$ distinct elements from $n$, what is the probability that at least one of the $k$ elements will *not* be in $S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1-$the probability that all of them are in $S$ so $1-\frac{\left({i\atop k}\right)}{\left({n\atop k}\right)}$. Here
$\left({i\atop k}\right)=0$ if $i<k$.